# How to use vhost-scsi with Intel P3700 NVME SSD in KVM

Tags: linux, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, proxmox, nvme

I am using proxmox beta 4 in my HP DL 380 server with KVM.  I configured Intel P3700 NVME - nvme0n1 as Virtio and on windows server 2008 r2 with virtio-scsi driver.

I am getting 100 K random IOPS when iothread is enabled.it works fine.
(the max capacity of the drive is 460 K , and in win2k8 bare metal it gets 350 K random iops!).

But I learned that "vhost-scsi" makes 200k IOPS and lower latency.
I am making the disk "SCSI" and "scsi controller" = "Virtio Scsi" , it works in the win2k8 guest as Redhat Virtio SCSI Passthrough, but it only gets
78k IOPS and cpu is overloaded.

I enabled CONFIG_VHOST_SCSI=m in vpe kernel config, but I don't know it is enough to do this.

How can I use vhost-scsi in proxmox?  How to enable, how to setup the disks, which drivers to use etc?

Comment: Good luck. This sounds like a complex setup. I'm pretty sure you won't find other people doing the same thing.

Comment: It sounds like it's working, just not performing as you want.  Is that correct?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/425607/126632